# XML declaration in Office 2013

Tags: xml, excel, vba, ms-office, office-2013

I have the follow VBA code to work with XML using Office 2010:

```
Public xmlDOM As DOMDocument

Public Sub setXML(xmlFileName As String)

    Set xmlDOM = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
    xmlDOM.async = False
    xmlDOM.Load xmlFileName

End Sub
```

OBS: There is a reference set to Microsoft XML, v6.0

BUT if I open the same code on Office 2013 I got an error that the

```
Public xmlDOM As DOMDocument
```

is not declared but there is still the reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0 set.

if I change

```
Public xmlDOM As DOMDocument
```

to

```
Public xmlDOM As MSXML.DOMDocument60
```

the compiler accepts but running the code I will get an error in

```
Set xmlDOM = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
```

even if I change it to

```
Set xmlDOM = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument60")
```

OBS: There is a reference set to Microsoft XML, v6.0 in Office 2013

What is going on?

Comment: Is your Excel 2013 64-bit and your Excel 2010 32-bit? Are they both on the same OS version?

Comment: Hi! Yes, one is 64-bit (2013) and other is 32-bits (2010). But I found a solution, I replaced "Public xmlDOM As DOMDocument" by "Public xmlDOM As MSXML2.DOMDocument60" and "Set xmlDOM = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")" by "Set xmlDOM = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60", it's working now fine for both versions

Comment: @Braulio You may move the answer from comment to answer section so that it can be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
Public xmlDOM As DOMDocument
```

with

```
Public xmlDOM As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
```

and

```
Set xmlDOM = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
```

with

```
Set xmlDOM = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
```